# Plot Tensor based on Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create a 3 dimensional tensor based on three numpy array. My idea is to create three 3 numpy arrays for the column, row and layer. Then I want to plot this tensor like the example image.
For instance a tensor like this one:
[image: 3 D Tensor]

I tried to create such a plot with matplotlib, but I understand that my approach is not working beacuse it tries to print the values within the tensor and not the shape of the tensor.
How can I plot a tensor like the one in the example?

Here is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def createRowCol():
    array= np.arange(25, dtype = 'float')
    matrix=np.matrix(array.reshape(5,5))
    return matrix

def createLayer():
    array = np.arange(6, dtype = 'float')
    matrix = np.matrix(array.reshape((3,2)))
    return matrix

row = createRowCol()
col = createRowCol()
layer = createLayer()

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(row,col,layer) # Error occurs because the "layer" has a different shape then "row" and "col"
plt.show()
```